# When will the java.awt.Robot fail to click?

Tags: java, awt

I use **java.awt.Robot** to perform some mouse behaviors on my PC. The code is simple like below:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class RobotProxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RobotProxy robotProxy = new RobotProxy();
        try {
            robotProxy.foo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Exception there...");
        }
    }

    public void foo() throws Exception{
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(501, 296);

        leftClick(robot);

        robot.mouseMove(505, 296);

        leftClick(robot);

        robot.mouseMove(509, 296);

        leftClick(robot);
    }

    public void leftClick(Robot robot) throws Exception{
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("before Click...");

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        System.out.println("after Click...");
    }

}
```

You can find that I use the combination of `java.awt.Robot.mousePress(InputEvent.Button1_MASK)` and `java.awt.Robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.Button1_MASK)` to perform the mouse left click behavior.

It works fine at most time but fails sometimes. For example, the left click behavior for a kind of software's check box will fail. I can make sure I send the click command to **java.awt.Robot** but just nothing happens. What's more incredible is that **java.awt.Robot.mouseMove(int x, int y)** still works in that situation.

PC's OS is Windows8.1

The software is not market available and it's just a Windows native app written by cpp. The button on the software can be clicked but not for check box.

If the situation makes you confused, pls just tell me when will the java.awt.Robot fail to click. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The difference between the press and the release might be to small.  Try using the `Robot#setAutoDelay` to introduce a delay between each event the `Robot` creates.  This happens a lot with keystrokes as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Fantastic, it can fix my problem. Thanks for your help.^_^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is no delay between the `robot.mousePress` and `robot.mouseRelease` commands.

Here is an example of what you could add in between the two to fix the issue
`Thread.sleep(100);` a delay for 100ms. about as fast as you can hear, *click click*